# Rename index influence

Tags: oracle, locking, alter

When I'm execute an `alter index <owner>.<name> rename to <new_name>`,

in goal to rename index, is that preventing any use of that index\table in queries?

Is that cause any lock?

I'm using Oracle 11g.

Comment: I don't think any sessions should be blocked, but cursors may be invalidated and require re-parsing. Also any hints containing hardcoded index names (not generally good practice, but it happens) will no longer have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

No, the name of an index has no bearing on how it is used by the Cost Based Optimizer.  Once renamed, the index will show up in the new explain plan and will be used in the same way it was used before.

Use the ONLINE parameter at the end of your ALTER INDEX in order to greatly reduce the chances of locks.

Comment: What if the index is in use right now and I'm trying to rename? Which locks are possible?